# Image displayed with black background OPENGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hi I am playing around with OPENGL Es on ANdroid and I am trying to display an image on my app. When I display the image ( image specs is 64x64 pixels ) I get a black background on the image but when I put this code:

```
 public void draw(GL10 gl) {
... 
.. 
 gl.glAlphaFunc( GL10.GL_GREATER, 0 );
```

The black background disappears but I get strange colors in my image.

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Posting a screenshot would be good. Posting some more code would be even better. Does your image contain an alpha channel? Does the code not shown contain any alpha testing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use blending.  Something like this should work:

```
gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA,gl.GL_ONE_MINE_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The fact that you can use `glAlphaFunc` and get *close* to your result suggests that the image itself is okay at least.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tried that but all I get is a full transparent images on top of one another. I already placed the following codes and still did not work.

Comment: gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, /*GL10.GL_REPLACE*/ GL10.GL_MODULATE);
      gl.glEnable( GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST ); 
     //  gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
       gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);      
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

Comment: I don't see any GL_BLEND in that line?

Comment: I finally figured out the problem, there was an extra gl.clearcolor and gl.clear4f lines somewhere in my code, after removing those extra lines, GL_BLEND worked like a charm... THanks!