# a bubble shooter game with android (balls appearance)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm making a small bubble shoot game on android with OpenGL ES.

So I want to make the balls explode when another ball collides with it! ..

But the problem here is so small but I can't find a solution for it,

I want the image to appear like figure (1) not like figure (2) ..

Right now the bubbles are appearing with a square border around them, but I do not want this. How can I remove the image borders?

Thanks a lot,
[image]

Comment: It's going to involve calculating the area of the rectangle and subtracting off the corner areas from the perimeter of the circle. Here's something to point you in the right direction:

Get the area of the circle (pi * radius * radius), find the area of the triangle (0.5 * base * height) areas of the square borders around the circle, and multiply the triangle area by 4. Then, subtract off that amount.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding !, I want to make that appear in the screen not what you thought, all what I meant that how can I make an image appear without boarders on the screen??! .. got me??!

Answer (score 4):

Do you know the center point of each circle? When the distance between 2 center points is the same as the sum of their to radii, then they are touching. You can do this by creating a right triangle and doing a^2 + b^2 = radius1^2 + radius2^2. Use the center points of the circles to create the triangles.

```
Bubble a,b
if((a.center.x - b.center.x)^2 + (a.center.y - b.center.y)^2 == (a.radius + b.radius)^2)
    //bubbles are touching
```

Comment: I think that people misunderstand me :( .. I meant the "appearance", how can I make the picture appear with its boarders not the " image " boarders if you knew what i mean??! .. got me?

Comment: Ohh. Does the image have a transparent background? I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Ok, I will be grateful if you found that for me!, I searched a lot :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063279/image-displayed-with-black-background-opengl-es-android

Comment: Thankssss a lot, But there another question :(, how can I make a transparent background in a png image?! is that normal as I thought or need something to do?!

Comment: You can use image editing software such as GIMP. You should be able to find someone who can do this for you, the png may already have a transparent layer.